# Using Hibernate Annotation mapping in Struts 2 + Spring + Hibernate project

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I'm following the tutorial of Mkyong to create project using Maven, Struts 2, Hibernate and Spring (http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-spring-hibernate-integration-example)

This tutorial using XML mapping to get data from Database. Actually I read some article about compare XML mapping and Annotation mapping.

_Current project struct:

[image]

[image]

_Source of Customer Model using XML mapping:

```
package com.mkyong.customer.model;

import java.util.Date;

public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable {

private Long customerId;
private String name;
private String address;
private Date createdDate;

public Customer() {
}

public Customer(String name, String address, Date createdDate) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}


public Long getCustomerId() {
    return this.customerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(Long customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}


public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public String getAddress() {
    return this.address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}


public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return this.createdDate;
}

public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

}
```

_Source of HibernateSession factory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
       </props>
    </property>

    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
          <value>com/mkyong/customer/hibernate/Customer.hbm.xml</value>          
        </list>
    </property> 

</bean>
</beans>
```

Now I want to change to use Annotation mapping, and update model class as:

```
pakage com.mkyong.customer.model

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="customer", catalog = "test")
public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long customerId;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private Date createdDate;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String name, String address, Date createdDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="customer_id")
    public Long getCustomerId() {
        return this.customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(Long customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    @Column(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name="address")
    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Column(name="created_date")
    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return this.createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

}
```

And update mapping section in HibernateSessionFactory :

```
 <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>        
          <value>com.mkyong.customer.model.Customer</value>
        </list>
 </property>
```

There're no error when run, but it's return 404 when I access to locahost/Struts2Example/listCustomerAction (this link work well with XML mapping)

I've tried to googling to using annotation mapping in this project, but it's fail.

So, can I using Annotation mapping instead of XML mapping in this project?

Please suggest me a simple solution or an example of using annotation mapping.

Comment: Yes, you can use annotations.

Comment: @AleksandrM could you give me some instruction to using annotation. I've tried to use javax.persistence.* and change the resource mapping in HibernateSessionFactory.xml but it's fail.

Comment: Show what have you tried and explain how it doesn't work.

Comment: Define persistence.xml (if using JPA), else define hibernate.cfg.xml and annotate the entities with appropriate annotations. Also post your exceptions & code & configuration which you have tried.